# height of the largest div to all div,s

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a few div(s) (like this image) inside in a parent div. I want to auto take , height of the largest div to all div(s). Is there solution with CSS ?
[image: example image]

Comment: `display: flex` on parent.

Comment: thanks a lot . i try display:flex but don't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic css height problem that is nicely solved by **flexbox**.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent .child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
}

.parent .child:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.parent .child .content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent .child:first-child .content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer here is flexbox. This will give you 3 columns, horizontally aligned, of the same height as the max height of the container (and the other children).

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-item"></div>
<div class="flex-item"></div>
<div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>

.flex-container { display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex; 
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
flex-flow: row wrap;
height:500px;} 

.flex-item { 
height:100%
display:block }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/tpg6gvsy/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with flexbox - **contains less code** (tweak values to your benefit):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parentDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parentDiv div {
  width: 33.3%;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.parentDiv div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div>Div 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex provident a eaque sequi. Sapiente, esse, animi! Debitis eius, officiis minus totam delectus iusto, tenetur corrupti quo officia quis minima tempore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Quibusdam consequuntur quaerat hic optio sint perspiciatis cumque doloribus blanditiis explicabo animi non eveniet aperiam, harum dolor, earum rem temporibus eos. Optio.</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```